# JQuery slider doesn't work fine for next slides ( having error with .next() )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image slider . It works fine if I press next button slowly . But when I press it consecutive , Next images will be shown without any fade effect and very irregular .

By the way , I tried `.stop()` before `.fade` effect and `.css`.

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/xocdq51a/15/

Comment: The jsfiddle does not work, a syntax error in the functions declarations.

Comment: @Loufylouf Oh... yes , But I don't know why ! because everything is similar to my code and it works out of jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xocdq51a/14/

Comment: @vel after I click on next button , everything will change to 0 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this its work good fine

you must add jquery library on jsfiddle first

and in your localhost add the code on head

```
 <head>
  <script>//Your code here </script>
 </head>
```

now you can check it here its look work good

Click [here to see it](http://jsfiddle.net/xocdq51a/15/)!

Comment: ok , now slider works , but my problem was another thing . look at the question. thansk